# How to separate variable "race" to make histograms for another variable

Tags: r, histogram

I have the following DataFrame:

```
head(SB_xlsx)

##   patnum hospstay    lowph pltct  race  bwt gest        inout twn lol magsulf
## 1      1       34       NA   100 white 1250   35 born at duke   0  NA      NA
## 2      2        9 7.250000   244 white 1370   32 born at duke   0  NA      NA
## 3      3       -2 7.059998   114 black  620   23 born at duke   0  NA      NA
## 4      4       40 7.250000   182 black 1480   32 born at duke   0  NA      NA
## 5      5        2 6.969997    54 black  925   28 born at duke   0  NA      NA
## 6      6       62 7.189999    NA white  940   28 born at duke   0  NA      NA
##   meth toc  delivery apg1 vent pneumo pda cld    sex dead
## 1    0   0 abdominal    8    0      0   0   0 female    0
## 2    1   0 abdominal    7    0      0   0   0 female    0
## 3    0   1   vaginal    1    1      0   0  NA female    1
## 4    1   0   vaginal    8    0      0   0   0   male    0
## 5    0   0 abdominal    5    1      1   0   0 female    1
## 6    1   0 abdominal    8    1      0   0   0 female    0
```

I need to create 4 histograms comparing birth weight (bwt) to each of the 4 races ("white", "black", "native american", and "oriental") under the "race" variable. How would I need to go about separating out the races so I could make the histograms for bwt?

I had to make a histogram for all of the bwts regardless of race, which the code is shown below. I know how to formulate histograms, but I'm not sure how to separate out races so I can make the 4 race specific ones.

```
hist(SB_xlsx$bwt, ylab="frequency", xlab="Birth Weight", main="Histogram of Birth Weight")
```

Comment: Does this work: `hist(subset(SB_xlsx, race == "white")$bwt, ylab="frequency", xlab="Birth Weight", main="Histogram of Birth Weight")`?

Comment: It appears to have worked, thank you! You can post the answer so I can upvote it if you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is quite simple, it's in the package `library(dplyr)`using the command `filter()`

Since I don't have your dataset, I made one up, with four races, under the column "bwt", and the other column, I called "height", this is what you will make a histogram with

```
# Create an empty data frame with column names
example_df <- data.frame( "bwt" = character(0), "height" = integer(0))
```

```
#Assign names to x 
variable_names <- c( "Black", "White", "Native-American", "Other")
```

```
# Assign names to y
w<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
x<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
y<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
z<-rnorm(200, mean=5, sd=2)
```

```
#combine everything to create dataframe (df)
df <- data.frame( "btw" = variable_names, "height" = c(w,x,y,z))
attach(df)
```

```
#load necessary package
library(dplyr)
```

```
# Use the filter() command to select the races you want
black = filter(df,btw=="Black")
white = filter(df,btw=="White")
native = filter(df,btw=="Native-American")
other = filter(df,btw=="Other")
```

```
# make histograms (I will only upload one image as an example here)
hist(black$height)
hist(white$height)
hist(native$height)
hist(other$height)
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
# you can also plot all 4 in one window

par(mfrow = c(2, 2), cex = 1)

hist(black$height,col="blue")
hist(white$height, col="green")
hist(native$height, col="orange")
hist(other$height, col="grey23")

'''

[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuWkx.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5rDp.png
```